# Add markers to a Ext.Map in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs

I am trying to make an application which displays a map with your current location marker and several markers related to data from the server which location is closed to your current location. So far I can render the map, show the current location and get the data related to this location. The problem arise when I try to add markers about the location of this data.
I´ve read through a lot of forums and pages but I found no solution. 
I use this piece of code to add markers (to try to add them ..):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map._map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(bookletMarker[i].location[1],bookletMarker[i].location[0]),
                    title : bookletMarker[i].title,
                    draggable:false,
                    icon: "point.png"
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

//This code renders a map with 2 points and displays the route to travel from point A to point B

//On Map Render

```
onMapMaprender: function(map, gmap, eOpts) {



    var record = Ext.getCmp('Panel').getData();
    var map = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#LocationMap')[0].getMap();
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline();
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'marker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 31),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 31)
    );


    var lat = record.data.latitude;
    var lon = record.data.longitude;
    console.log(lat,lon);

    var destinationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: markerImage,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        title : 'destination',
        map: map,
    })
    var latSrc = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lonSrc = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var sourceMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: markerImage,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latSrc,lonSrc),
        title : 'source',
        map: map,
    })


    function dir_callback(a,b){
        g=a;
        route_no=0;
        if(b=="OK"){
            var polyarr = a.routes[route_no].overview_path;
            polyline.setPath(polyarr);
            polyline.setMap(map);
        }
    }

    var dirS = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var req = {
        origin: sourceMarker.getPosition(),
        destination: destinationMarker.getPosition(),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        provideRouteAlternatives : true
    };
    dirS.route(req,dir_callback);

},
```

//Setting the Map

var cr = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
Ext.getCmp('LocationMap').setMapCenter(cr);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the map instance from your map with getMap() and then add the pointer as described in the google maps api docs:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.getMap()` to get the google map instance and use it when you create markers.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Something I've noticed, the maprender event doesn't fire and if I use the painted event, nothing is passed into the 2nd argument. Only the 1st arg is populated with a DOM element. Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have directly added icon image path, instead use MarkerImage object as follow,

```
var imageIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "point.png",
            new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(16, 31)
        );

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map._map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(bookletMarker[i].location[1],bookletMarker[i].location[0]),
                title : bookletMarker[i].title,
                draggable:false,
                icon: imageIcon 
            });
```